# resample Pandas dataframe and merge strings in column

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I want to resample a pandas dataframe and apply different functions to different columns. The problem is that I cannot properly process a column with strings. I would like to apply a function that merges the string with a delimiter such as " - ". This is a data example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-31', '2017-02-03')
data=list([[1,10,"ok"],[2,20,"merge"],[3,30,"us"]])
dates=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-31','2017-02-03','2017-02-03'])
d=pd.DataFrame(data, index=,columns=list('ABC'))

            A   B          C
2017-01-31  1  10         ok
2017-02-03  2  20      merge
2017-02-03  3  30         us
```

Resampling the numeric columns A and B with a sum and mean aggregator works. Column C however kind of works with sum (but it gets placed on the second place, which might mean that something fails).

```
d.resample('D').agg({'A': sum, 'B': np.mean, 'C': sum})

              A               C     B
2017-01-31  1.0               a  10.0
2017-02-01  NaN               0   NaN
2017-02-02  NaN               0   NaN
2017-02-03  5.0        merge us  25.0
```

I would like to get this:

```
...
2017-02-03  5.0      merge - us  25.0
```

I tried using lambda in different ways but without success (not shown).

If I may ask a second related question: I can do some post processing for this, but how to fill missing cells in different columns with zeros or ""?

Comment: IIUC, you can use df.fillna() to fill in missing values. 

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: yes sure, and possibly apply different replacements (eg 0, None, "") to different columns. I was wondering if there was a more elagant way to do it in .resample

Answer (score 7):

Your agg function for column `'C'` should be a `join`

```
d.resample('D').agg({'A': sum, 'B': np.mean, 'C': ' - '.join})

              A     B           C
2017-01-31  1.0  10.0          ok
2017-02-01  NaN   NaN            
2017-02-02  NaN   NaN            
2017-02-03  5.0  25.0  merge - us
```

Comment: Ah, so the "input" to the functions are iterables and I can use a function taking iterables as inputs. I can build a function taking an iterable if I need to do fancier operations. 
Strange, in my console I still see column C in the second place.